# How can I get Debug.WriteLine data (or similar output) on an Azure App Services website?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

On my local development machine, I am using **System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline** to output select data to my screen.  I also have an **Azure App Services** website for testing.  There, I would also like to keep **Debug.Writeline** outputting data but obviously I don't have a monitor connected directly to such a computer.  Is there a way to output data from my code and then retrieve+view such data from the Azure website?

On the Azure portal, there is a section called Monitoring with a sub-node Logs.  But, I cannot figure out either how to output to such a log or even on the portal what to click to enable logging or view logs.  Nothing is intuitive about this.  I don't even knowing if **Debug.Writeline** is captured in any such logs.  So is there a way to capture and view the data?   I can use an alternate method instead of **Debug.WriteLine** if another is better for this purpose.

And, in a perfect world, I would like to view the data in realtime, where it scrolls like it does on my local development machine.  Is there any technology like that?  But, I'll take even basic log files if a live view is not possible.

Comment: Q: What language are you using?  C#?  Or "something else"?  Q: Have you looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Comment: In a perfect world, you should learn what Azure already offers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console

Comment: @FoggyDay, C# but the question is not language specific.  I did review the links you shared, thanks, before I posted.  I could not get such logging to work, however.

Comment: @Lex Li, I DID read first before posting.  I can see what Azure offers but it's not intuitive and clearly I don't know which of many, many logging options to utilize and how.   I have read much and tried things but with no success.

Comment: Q: Have you tried "Trace" instead of "Debug"?  Q: Have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) link, which specifies a) How to enable logging, and b) where to find the logs once they're enabled?  If you're still not able to "get logging to work", then please post sample code and describe how you tested it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the System.Diagnostics.Trace class instead of System.Diagnostics.Debug and it will work.

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#add-log-messages-in-code

Also you can forward those logs to Azure Monitor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor-preview