# Not able to debug Azure function V4 with Timer Trigger from Visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to run/debug a new Azure function (V4, dotnet 6.0) from Visual Studio 2022. The function uses `TimerTrigger` and to debug it I tried using `RunOnStartup = true` in the `TimerTriggerAttribute`. I also tried a `POST` call to `http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/<functionName>` with an empty request body `{}` from the postman. But no luck. The debugger won't hit the function.

I've another function decorated with `HttpTrigger`, which runs successfully. But the one with `TimerTrigger` is not getting called.

Below is the code for the function and the related settings.

**Function**

```
namespace ImageAnalysisFunction
{
    public class ImageAnalysis
    {

        [FunctionName("ImageAnalysis")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Timer triggered at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        }
    }

}
```

**local.sttings.json**

```
{
   "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
   }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(ImageAnalysisFunction.Startup))]
namespace ImageAnalysisFunction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Startup class to configure dependency injection, swagger and other stuff
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        /// <inherit />
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
        }

        /// <inherit />
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder);
#if DEBUG
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();
            builder
              .ConfigurationBuilder
              .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

**Runtime output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions is built on top of the App Service Infrastructure.

`Debug.WriteLine` method writes the information to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection about the debug.

As given in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60780612),  `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class instead of `Debug` is the better approach given for adding the log messages to application logs.

**Azure Function .NET 6 Timer Trigger - VS 2022**
[image: AzFuncNet6TimerTriggerDebugVS2022]